# Can I move a Bluemix service to a different org

Tags: ibm-cloud

I created a Bluemix service in my "Dev" org for testing.  Now I want to move it to a different org.  Is there a way to just *move* or transfer the existing service or do I have to create a whole new one in the new org?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving services between orgs is not possible. You will need to to create a new service in the new org.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't found the option to transfer it to another account but it isn't difficult:

1º Edit your manifest.yml
applications:
- name: new-service-name
...

2º cf login -a https://api.ng.bluemix.net 
with the login and password in the new organization

3º cf push new-service-name

Comment: This does NOT move Services. The method described here simply pushes your Application to the new org/space with a new application name. Services are different than applications.